# Limit of $ x^{x^{x-1}} $

Tags: limits

Can you help to calculate the limit of the following function

$\lim_\limits{x\to 0^+} x^{x^{x-1}} $

I have tried it using exponential of logarithm as:

$\lim_\limits{x\to 0^+} x^{x^{x-1}}=\lim_\limits{x\to 0^+} e^{ln{x^{x^{x-1}}}}  $

But couldnt get the answer

Comment: I think u asked it already

Comment: This is $0$, isn't it?  It might be easier to figure out as $\lim_{y \to +\infty} (1/y)^{(1/y)^{-(1-1/y)}} = \lim_{y \to +\infty} (1/y)^{y^{1-1/y}}$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $0$, since one has specified $0^{+}$ as the point you approach. Otherwise, if you approached $0$ itself, it would be indeterminate.

You write $$\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} x^{x^{x-1}} = \lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \exp(\ln x^{x^{x-1}}) = \lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \exp(x^{x-1}\ln x)$$
Since the numerator of 
$$ \frac{x^x \ln x}{x}$$ is hugely negative (notice that $x^x \to 1$ here), but the denominator is going to $0^{+}$, so the exponent is $-\infty$, and so we have the limit as $\exp(-\infty) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

You almost there :)
Now all you need is to calculate the lim of
$$  x^{x-1}lnx$$
Which is equal to
$$ln(x)\x^{1-x}$$
And you know that ln(x) is converge to $-\infty$
And $$x^{1-x}$$ converge to 0
So $$ln(x)/(x^{1-x})$$ converge to $-\infty$
Which mwans $$e^{ln(x)/x^{1-x}}$$ converges to 0